# How to properly fulfill Apache 2.0 in commercial Android products at Google Play?

Tags: apache-2.0, android, google-play

Given the plethora of Apache 2.0 libraries used to create many proprietary Android apps, how/where should we refer to the Apache License?

1. Should we mention Apache license at Google Play, presenting a link to the full license?
2. Mention in Google Play is enough or we also must add it into the installed APK?
3. Should the binary contain the full license or a link is enough?
4. Should each Apache library be discriminated (like Instagram) or simply mention it once is enough to cover all Apache dependencies?

Comment: Did you read "4. Redistribution" of the Apache License text? 4.a. says only that you give the recipients the license; if you link to the license it is your responsibility to ensure that the link is always operational; if the site goes down, for example, that is on you, not the site operator. 4.d implies that you should add attribution notices into a screen typically used for this purpose in your application, e.g. "About", "Notice", "Credits", etc.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the apps provide a page containing third party library information.
This would be the easiest way to fulfil the license obligations.

For Apache v2 you would have to display:

- the Copyright information (this can be found in the source code)
- the complete license text (complete because in absence of an internet connection the user would not be able to know the rights given by the license text.)

Comment: It would be great if down-votes would be accompanied by comments.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Even if you look at how "well known apps  have done it", it is not necessarily how it should be done. Maybe those apps are not doing it properly, or maybe they have other arrangements with the publishers of the libraries in question. Ultimately you have to read what the license says to attempt to answer this.

Comment: @Brandin You are right. I will change the answer.